# Replacing the Google logo with a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I made an extension which is supposed to replace the Google logo of the search results page with another picture. Since the img tag of the logo doesn't have an own class or id, I had to do it kinda weird by changing the innerHTML of the closest parent div with a class.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "Logo Replacer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "images/*.png"
    ],
    "description": "Replaces Google logo",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],

    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : [
                "<all_urls>" //normally I want only google.com here but idk how
            ],
            "js": ["changePicture.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**changePicture.js:**

```
var googleLogo = document.getElementsByClassName("doodle"); //the parent div has the classes "logo" and "doodle"

googleLogo.innerHTML = "<a href=\"https://www.google.com\" data-hveid=\"8\"><img alt=\"Alt\" height=\"33\" src=\"https://example.com/logo.png\" title=\"Title\" width=\"92\" border=\"0\" data-atf=\"1\"></a>";
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? Are you having any errors / issues?

Comment: @PraneetDixit No errors and my issue is that it's doing nothing. I imported it into Chrome and nothing happens. It's supposed to change the Google logo on the top left of a page like https://google.com/search?q=google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an `html collection object`. To select the particular first element with this class, you have to specify the index like this -

```
var googleLogo = document.getElementsByClassName("doodle")[0];
```

You can also simplify you approach using `querySelector` to get the specific `img` and then change the `src` like below -

```
document.querySelector(".logo.doodle a img").src = "Your desired source"
```